# ResponseStream re-read after read timeout

Tags: c#, timeout, webresponse, responsestream

I am wondering when I read a response stream and a timeout occurs, can I retry the read?  Or do I have to make a new request?  The server that I am downloading from does not support resuming, so I need to protect against timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't retry. You need to reissue the request

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that the server doesn't accept resumes? Is the [`Accept-Ranges`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5) header indeed lacking in the response? If not, you could resume the request using the [`Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header.

If the server indeed doesn't support it, then best what you can try is to inform the server that you want to keep the connection alive using `Connection: keep-alive` header in combination with the [`Keep-Alive`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/draft-ietf-http-v11-spec-01.html#Keep-Alive) header wherein you can specify the timeout.

Hope this helps.